# Creating, adding, updating and selecting data from virtual table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, c#-4.0

I'm looking for a method in **C#** to do virtual table as database table.

I would like to add datas line by line,
As:

**ID** - **NameOfData** - **Value** - **Date** - **SomeText** - **OtherID**

1 - testing - g12gh - 12.01.2012 - testing text - 12

and selecting, update it. I don't want to save it to somewhere, because values can be change second by second...

Is there a method to do it quickly as working with database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be enough.

You might need to use Session or Cache to store the DataTable across multiple requests and also to share the Datatable between different users.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would say: create a class or struct with properties ID,  NameOfData, Value, Date, SomeText, OtherID, etc and store you data e.g. in a List of objects of this class. It's the easiest way for storing data in C#, temporarily, without persistance, with CRUD possibilities.

Inserting can be done easily: `myList.Add(newItem)`
Updating: `myList[id] = updatedItem`
Removing: `myList.Remove(id)`
Reading the whole collection : e.g. via foreach loop